# Dynamically toggle visibility of table row - bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Is there a way to dynamically hide / show (display) a table row in a dynamic bootstrap-vue table?

I'm currently using the `_rowVariant` prop to create a class on the row, which is working, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to additionally connect the `show_old_projects` value to the row's display... since the rows are added dynamically.

```
<b-form-checkbox v-model="show_old_projects" value="true" unchecked-value="false">
  Show old projects
</b-form-checkbox>

<b-table :fields="fields" :items="projects" :filter="filter"></table>

...

validateProjects() {
  for (const project of this.projects){
    if (project.end_date < this.date) {
      project._rowVariant = 'muted'; 
    }
  }
}

...

.table-muted {
  @extend .text-muted;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [bootstrap-vue docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/)

Comment: You could just watch the show_old_projects value and validateProjects() when it changes? If you want to completely remove the row from the table, you could remove the project from the items array.

Comment: Thanks man, you helped clear up the fog in my head!

Comment: Pre-filtering the items data before passing it to `b-table` would be your best bet. you can use Javascript's built in [`Array.prototype.filter(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

- created 2 arrays `projects` and `old_projects`
- created another table for `old_projects` below the `projects` table
- added a `v-show="show_old_projects"` to the `old_projects` table
- upon fetching the data, I iterated through it and organized the projects into their respective arrays

If somebody can think of a cleaner way to do this I'm open to suggestions... otherwise this is working fine.